# What is the name on my customers' credit card?

Tags: visual, knowledge

I run a department store in Bangor, Maine. Today I had a call from a customer whom lost his credit card. I actually found a couple lost credit cards over the last few weeks, so I asked him what the name on his credit card is. He told me he would send a picture of his credit card. Instead, he sent me this:

> Hey,
>
> Thanks for checking out if you found my credit card. The credit card looks like this:
>   
>   Please tell me if you found it, so I can pick it up.
>
> Sent from my iPhone

What is the name of the customer, which is written on his credit card?

Comment: For some reason, I have the feeling that I've seen this puzzle before ? Yet I can't find any similar one in PSE.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know I did some research before posting. Searching the solution to this challenge on google (targeting only puzzling.stackexchange.com) yields no results of similar puzzles.

Comment: That's what I figured. Oh well, great puzzle by the way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

His name is

> John Appleseed, as explained [here](https://emojipedia.org/credit-card/)
> The official Apple artwork for this shows an authorized signature for John Appleseed, with 448 as the security code.

Comment: I indeed seem to have that credit card laying around here. Thanks for the help! :-)